# Print a 256-color test pattern in the terminal

Tags: colors

I want to check that my terminal supports 256 colours.

How do I print a 256-colour test pattern in my terminal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been cross-posted to http://askubuntu.com/questions/821157/print-a-256-color-test-pattern-in-the-terminal. Please read [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/).

Answer (score 2):

**256-colour test pattern**

[image: 256-colour test pattern]

For the above, you can use [my bash code](https://gist.github.com/HaleTom/89ffe32783f89f403bba96bd7bcd1263).

Or for a bash quicky:

```
for i in {0..255} ; do
    printf "\x1b[38;5;${i}m%3d " "${i}"
    if (( $i == 15 )) || (( $i > 15 )) && (( ($i-15) % 12 == 0 )); then
        echo;
    fi
done
```

Comment: You got any details about that color code structure inside `printf`? Any documentation about that?

Comment: They're [ANSI CSI sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences)